# Can anyone please help? Unable to import project into WaveMaker

Tags: project, project-settings

I am trying to import my project's zip file into WaveMaker. But after all attempts,I am getting error-Failed to open the project.

I am using:
- WaveMaker 6.3.2GA
- Windows 7

It asked to add jar files.I have downloaded and added into its lib folder.But It still giving me the same error. 
[image]
Can anyone please guide me whats the actual problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I have copied extracted folder in to root directory. And open it from WaveMaker. It Works.

Answer (score 0):

Open the wavemaker in Administrator mode and add the jar file